# Instantiate array of associated type in Swift

Tags: swift, generics

I'm going through the "Guided Tour" playground that comes with Swift 2.2. In the chapter on generics, you get this extraordinarily cumbersome function declaration dumped on you:

```
func anyCommonElements <T: SequenceType, U: SequenceType where
    T.Generator.Element: Equatable,
    T.Generator.Element == U.Generator.Element>
    (lhs: T, _ rhs: U) -> Bool {

  for lhsItem in lhs {
      for rhsItem in rhs {
          if lhsItem == rhsItem {
              return true
          }
      }
  }
 return false

}
anyCommonElements([1, 2, 3], [3])
```

The function returns whether or not two sequences have any elements in common, which is simple enough.

The exercise for this chapter is to modify the function to return an Array of the common elements between the two sequences. From this I get that the function needs to have a return type like

```
(lhs: T, _ rhs: U) -> [T.Generator.Element]
```

Which seems simple enough, make an array and put the common elements in it, then return it. But nothing in the book so far has taught me how to make a new array of type `[T.Generator.Element]`, so I don't really know how to proceed. I naturally assumed something like this would work:

```
var result = [T.Generator.Element]()
```

But yeah, that doesn't compile. So how do I solve this exercise? (And isn't this a little advanced for the *first introduction of generics*?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, it should work. That it doesn't is [a known bug in the Swift compiler](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-773). You have several options for a workaround:

- `var result: [T.Generator.Element] = []`
- `var result = [] as [T.Generator.Element]`
- `var result = Array<T.Generator.Element>()`

(The trick is to give the compiler enough context that it knows it's trying to parse a type name there. In the `[T.Generator.Element]()` syntax it incorrectly parses the bracketed portion as an array literal.)